# Perl Validate Regex and Loop Captures

Tags: regex, perl, validation

I need to validate a string like "[one.two.three]", where titles are separated by ".", there has to be a minimum of at least one title. Each title needs to be extracted. Is there any way to do this in a loop or does it have to be two separate steps?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @tests = ("[one]", "[two.three.four]");

foreach (@tests) {
    while ($_ =~ /^\[(\w+)(?:\.\w+)*\]$/) {
        print "$1\n";
    }

    print "\n\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Totally didn't think of split(). So basically use regex to validate format and allowed characters and then split for each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense to separate the validation and extraction:

```
my ($titles) = $input =~ /^\[((?:\w+|\b\.\b)+)\]\z/
    or die "invalid input $input.\n";
my @title = split /\./, $titles;
```

Though you could do it all at once, I think the readability suffers:

```
my @title = split /\./, ( $input =~ /^\[((?:\w+|\b\.\b)+)\]\z/ )[0] // ''
    or die "invalid input $input.\n";
```